# ViewPager + FragmentStatePagerAdapter: How to recreate all fragment with new adapter

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I'm using the v4 compatibility library. I have a Fragment Tabhost, the first tab have a ViewPager using FragmentStatePagerAdapter. The problem is when I switch to other tabs, change data of the first tab's ViewPager, then return to the first tab, recreate new Adapter with new data and set it to ViewPager, but the first 3 fragments in ViewPager still hold reference to old data.

My code in the first tab to create adapter (called in onCreateView method):

```
private void setPagerData() {
    if (mPager == null || AppConfig.getInstance().todayData == null)
        return;

    if (AppConfig.getInstance().todayData != null && !AppConfig.getInstance().todayData.isEmpty()) {
        //
        mPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(AppConfig.PAGER_OFFSCREEN_PAGE_LIMIT);
        mPager.setAlwaysDrawnWithCacheEnabled(true);
        //
        mAdapter = new TodayPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager(), AppConfig.getInstance().todayData);
        mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        if (mAdapter.getCount() == 1)
            mPager.setCurrentItem(0);
        else
            mPager.setCurrentItem(1);

        text_currentpage.setText("1");
        text_totalpage.setText(String.valueOf(mAdapter.getCount() - 2));
        anim_numpage = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(TodayFragment.this.getActivity(), R.anim.fade_numpage);
        layout_numpage.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        image_nextpage.setOnClickListener(this);
        image_prevpage.setOnClickListener(this);
        //
        mPager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);

    } else
        onNoData(true);
}
```

onDestroyView():

```
public void onDestroyView() {
    AppUtils.Log("Destroy view Today Fragment");
    mAdapter = null;
    mPager = null;
    super.onDestroyView();
}
```

My Adapter:

```
    public class TodayPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    private List<PostDTO> posts;
    private FragmentManager fm;

    public TodayPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<PostDTO> posts) {
        super(fm);
        this.fm = fm;
        this.posts = posts;
        if (posts == null)
            posts = new ArrayList<PostDTO>();
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int page) {
        if (page == 0 && posts.size() > 1)
            return TodayPagerFragment.init(posts.size() - 1, posts.get(posts.size() - 1));
        if (page == posts.size() + 1)
            return TodayPagerFragment.init(0, posts.get(0));
        if (posts.size() > 1)
            return TodayPagerFragment.init(page - 1, posts.get(page - 1));
        return TodayPagerFragment.init(page, posts.get(page));
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        if (posts.size() <= 1)
            return posts.size();
        return posts.size() + 2;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
        return POSITION_NONE;
    }
}
```

My ViewPager's Fragment:

```
    public class TodayPagerFragment extends AbstractFragment implements View.OnClickListener {

    int page;

    private ImageView iv_image;
    private LikeButton button_like;
    private PostDTO data;

    public static TodayPagerFragment init(int val, PostDTO data) {
        TodayPagerFragment frm = new TodayPagerFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt("page", val);
        frm.setArguments(args);
        frm.data = data;
        return frm;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        page = getArguments() != null ? getArguments().getInt("page") : 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_today_viewpager, container, false);
        setupView(view);

        iv_image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.today_viewpager_image);
        button_like = (LikeButton) view.findViewById(R.id.today_button_like);
        button_like.setUp(true);

        initViews();
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.today_viewpager_image:
            ((BaseContainerFragment) getParentFragment().getParentFragment()).replaceFragment(TodayDetailFragment.init(this.data), true);
            break;

        case R.id.today_button_like:
            if (!AppConfig.getInstance().isLoggedIn || AppConfig.getInstance().appUser == null) {
                AppUtils.openLogin(getActivity());

            } else {
                String ms = getString(R.string.do_you_want_to_like_this_post_);
                if (data.isLiked())
                    ms = getString(R.string.do_you_want_to_unlike_this_post_);
                new MyDialogHandler().confirm(getActivity(), getString(R.string.like_confirm), ms, getString(R.string.no), getString(R.string.yes), new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        new PostLikeTask(button_like, data, !data.isLiked()).execute();
                        // data.setLiked(!data.isLiked());
                    }
                }, null);
            }
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }
    }

    // Setup view data
    private void initViews() {
        iv_image.setOnClickListener(this);
        button_like.setOnClickListener(this);

        if (this.data != null) {
            AppUtils.Log("Current: //////// " + (data.toString().equals(AppConfig.getInstance().todayData.get(page))));
            // if (AppConfig.getInstance().appUser != null &&
            // AppConfig.getInstance().isLoggedIn)
            // new GetLikedTask().execute();
            // else
            button_like.setData(data.getLikes(), data.isLiked());
            // ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(AppConfig.SERVER_IMAGE_URL
            // + this.data.getImage(), iv_image);
            // onLoading(true);
            UrlImageViewHelper.setUrlDrawable(iv_image, AppConfig.SERVER_IMAGE_URL + this.data.getImage());
        }
    }
}
```